# Poisson or binomial regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, count-data

I have a binary response variable (it is a presence/absence variable) and a ordinal discrete predictor:

```
response : [1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ... ]
predictor : [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ... ]
```

I'd like to know whether there is a higher probability to encounter whatever is recorded in the response variable when the levels of the predictor is higher or lower.

Do I have better to perform a Binary GLM: `response ~ predictor`

Or do I have better to count the number of occurrences (number of one in `response`) in each level of the predictor and run a Poisson GLM: `response2 ~ predictor2`

```
response2 : [15 22 21]
predictor2 : [1 2 3]
```

1: Are both models correct? What is the difference?

2: Is there a difference between Binary GLM and logistic regression? Is one a special case of the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1: Are both correct? What is the difference?

If you want to model the probability of occurrence based on the level of the predictor then you want to use logistic regression (a type of binomial GLM).  For example, the probability  of defaulting on a loan based on marital status.

If you want to model the number of events based on the predictor level then you would use the Poisson GLM.  For example, the number of loans someone will default on in next five years based on marital status.

I think you want logistic regression

> 2: Is there a difference between Binary GLM and logistic regression? Is one a special case of the other?

The binomial GLM in R where `glm(..., family = binomial)` is logistic regression.

There are binomial regressions other than logistic regression that use different link functions.  Logistic regression uses logit.  You can also specify probit and others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In order to make sure I understand the difference between the two models: Let's say I have observed fishes in environments that have low/middle/high human impact factor. When using a Poisson GLM I get a non significant p.value and with a logistic regression I get a significant p.value. Accepting once the null and once the alternative hypothesis what does it mean about the effect that the human impact factor has on my fishes? Do these two tests really mean something different?

Comment: It would mean that there is a higher probability to meet a fish in an non_impacted environment (logistic model) but there is no more fishes in one type of environment than in the other (Poisson GLM). Is it correct? Does it mean something for my fishes?

Comment: This is oversimplified. Choosing a binomial family does not automatically mean that you should or must choose a logit link. Probit, complementary log-log and log-log are just some of the other possibilities.

Comment: @Remi.b  Are the observations carried out for the exact same time period in each environment?  They should be to use Poisson.

Comment: @Nick Cox  Yes, good point, there are other link functions but he was asking about logistic regression.

Comment: You still say "The binomial GLM ... is logistic regression". That is only correct if "is" means "includes".

Comment: @DirkCalloway Yes the data were taken within the same time period at different sites. Why would you use a Poisson GLM rather than a logistic regression?

Comment: @NickCox You are right, but, in my experience (and also from some reading) those models usually give very similar answers. (Of course, that doesn't mean they always do).

Comment: @PeterFlom Sure, but the question was "Is there a difference between Binary GLM and logistic regression? Is one a special case of the other?" and the answer is Yes, logistic regression is a special case of the binary GLM. The present answer from Dirk Calloway remains misleading if not incorrect. I don't want to be heavy-handed and edit it myself.

Comment: To model a probability I would use logistic regression.  Each model has it's own way to deal with the constraints imposed upon it.  LR uses log odds to model a 0-1 probability range Poisson regressions assumes a Poisson distribution and uses a log $E(Y|X)$ to deal with positive integers.  But I wouldn't expect them to give wildly different signals.  How "non-significant" are the Poisson p-values?

Comment: @NickCox  Given that the default link function is logit I'm not sure how the above command is misleading.  If he wanted probit, etc. he'd need to specify the link in the command.

Comment: What happens by default in a particular piece of software is not automatically a definition of a statistical method. If I use Stata's `glm` I get by default Gaussian family, identity link i.e. classical linear regression. Would you say that means GLM _is_ linear regression? I doubt it. "The binomial GLM in R where glm(..., family = binomial) is logistic regression." to me remains a misleading statement.

Comment: @NickCox Fair enough... added a caveat above.